# Python Function That Receives String, Returns String + "!"

Tags: python, string, function, return

As the title suggests, I'm just trying to create a Python function that receives a string, then returns that string with an exclamation point added to the end.

An input of "Hello" should return

```
Hello!
```

An input of "Goodbye" should return

```
Goodbye!
```

Etc.

Here's what I tried:

```
def addExclamation(s):
    s = input("please enter a string")
    new_string = s + "!"
    return new_string

print(s(addExclamation))
```

This gave me the error message:

```
NameError: name 's' is not defined on line 6
```

Why is "s" not defined? I thought I determined that s is the input within the `addExclamation` function. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are mixing up everything.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 What am I mixing up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You define a function with a parameter `s`. That function immediately throws that value away and asks for input. You are calling a function with the same name as that parameter, and sending it an argument of the function name. That doesn't make any sense.

```
def addExclamation(s):
    new_string = s + "!"
    return new_string

print(addExclamation('Hello'))
```

Or:

```
def addExclamation():
    s = input("please enter a string")
    new_string = s + "!"
    return new_string

print(addExclamation())
```

Answer (score 1):

You have *mixed up the function and the argument* here:

```
print(s(addExclamation))
```

And, you probably meant to read the input outside of a function and pass the string into:

```
def addExclamation(s):
    new_string = s + "!"
    return new_string

s = input("please enter a string")
print(addExclamation(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

In the statement:

```
s(addExclamation)
```

You try to call the `s` function which is not defined.

The parameter you give `addExclamation` is the function you want to call. You should write:

```
addExclamation("Hello")
```

In this example, you call the function `addExclamation()` with a string parameter: "hello".

But you need to change its implementation:

```
def addExclamation(s):
    result = s + "!"
    return result
```

This implementation is self-explanatory: it creates a new string `result` with the concatenation of the original string `s` and "!".

If you want to use `input`, you can do:

```
text = input("Enter a text: ")
print(addExclamation(text))
```